# Pandas - How to roll forward monthly values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data:

```
Key                 Balance Date    Monthly Yield
ETH Staking - STETH 2023-02-28      2.22341172
ETH Staking - STETH 2023-03-31      2.50258494
ETH Staking - STETH 2023-04-30      2.20200929
ETH Staking - STETH 2023-05-31      3.23329313
```

I am struggling to roll forward the data, to obtain the following result, where the suppose that February would create three new rows for any future months. It should just have the February value, but appear newly for each month. Similarly, March would appear the same value for any amount of future months available to it.

Output expected:

[image]

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the example structure remains consistent, you can do this by using `pd.concat` while looping through all your balance dates.

```
dfs = []
for date in df['Balance Date'].unique():
    qwe = df[df['Balance Date'] >= date].copy()
    qwe['Monthly Yield'] = qwe[qwe['Balance Date'] == date]['Monthly Yield'].item()
    dfs.append(qwe)
pd.concat(dfs)
```

Ouput:

```
                   Key Balance Date  Monthly Yield
0  ETH Staking - STETH   2023-02-28       2.223412
1  ETH Staking - STETH   2023-03-31       2.223412
2  ETH Staking - STETH   2023-04-30       2.223412
3  ETH Staking - STETH   2023-05-31       2.223412
1  ETH Staking - STETH   2023-03-31       2.502585
2  ETH Staking - STETH   2023-04-30       2.502585
3  ETH Staking - STETH   2023-05-31       2.502585
2  ETH Staking - STETH   2023-04-30       2.202009
3  ETH Staking - STETH   2023-05-31       2.202009
3  ETH Staking - STETH   2023-05-31       3.233293
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

make Series of DatetimeIndex till '2023-05-31'

```
s = df['Balance Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x, '2023-05-31', freq='M'))
```

`s`

```
0    DatetimeIndex(['2023-02-28', '2023-03-31', '2023-04-30', '2023-05-31'])
1    DatetimeIndex(['2023-02-28', '2023-03-31', '2023-04-30'])
2    DatetimeIndex(['2023-04-30', '2023-05-31'])
3    DatetimeIndex(['2023-05-31'])
```

modify `Balance Date` column by s & explode & ffill

```
df.assign(**{'Balance Date': s}).explode('Balance Date').ffill()
```

output:

```
    Key               Balance Date  Monthly Yield
0   ETH Staking - STETH 2023-02-28  2.223412
0   ETH Staking - STETH 2023-03-31  2.223412
0   ETH Staking - STETH 2023-04-30  2.223412
0   ETH Staking - STETH 2023-05-31  2.223412
1   ETH Staking - STETH 2023-03-31  2.502585
1   ETH Staking - STETH 2023-04-30  2.502585
1   ETH Staking - STETH 2023-05-31  2.502585
2   ETH Staking - STETH 2023-04-30  2.202009
2   ETH Staking - STETH 2023-05-31  2.202009
3   ETH Staking - STETH 2023-05-31  3.233293
```

if you want edit index, use `reset_index(drop=True)`

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Key': ['ETH Staking - STETH', 'ETH Staking - STETH', 'ETH Staking - STETH', 'ETH Staking - STETH'], 
        'Balance Date': ['2023-02-28', '2023-03-31', '2023-04-30', '2023-05-31'], 
        'Monthly Yield': [2.22341172, 2.50258494, 2.20200929, 3.23329313]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Balance Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Balance Date'])
```